# Data section of program is too big or not?

Tags: c, memory

I am kinda new to c, so i wrote this simple program. i just have two int variables.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){

  int x = 3;
  int y = 4;
  printf("x = %d \n y = %d",x,y);
  return 0;
}
```

So when i analysed its image `EXE`. i found that data section was a 12 KB is it normal or there is something i cant see, i mean my program size including PE header,code and imports measures 72 KB size of my `SECOND.EXE`

Comment: sorry for header files :)

Comment: other than data section your program  have text section and BSS also.

Comment: i measured text + rdata +PE header in immunity debugger it was 72KB but data shows additional 12 KB?

Comment: Not sure about this particular case, however if you use `printf` you need  libraries. Your program can contain standard library either statically linked or it must contain some code to dynamically link it. This code needs some variables and takes some place too.

Comment: Dayal rai - BSS is externally used by object file so it wont interfere with my programs memory.

Comment: This seems to be running under windows,  even so, an effort should be made to NOT #include <conio.h>  as it is non-portable.   Was the program run with debug enabled ( usually the compile/link parameter of '-ggdb')  if so, then a large portion of the .data section is the info used by gdb.

Answer (score 1):

You compiler source file is just the generated code from the actual source file and not much else. An executable have been linked with other object files and libraries, needed for all external functions and variables you need. That of course makes the executable much bigger as it contains much more code. It contains other things which are needed to run your program perfectly.

Comment: "You compiler source file is ..." What do you mean? What _source file_?

Comment: That is **not** a _source file_! `.text`, `.data`, `.const`/`.rodata`, etc. are sections in an _object file_! Something very different. And `PE header` is something different - a header structure.

Comment: Compiler source file means the object file (xx.o)

Comment: So correct it! A car is not a motor. Source is source, not object, not sink.

Comment: uditr but why are those linked files running under my programs address space?

Comment: Wouldn't it be compromising memory security of my program? i mean if those files can manipulate variables in my address space. then its a dam malware!

Comment: http://cs-fundamentals.com/c-programming/memory-layout-of-c-program-code-data-segments.php  C is very powerful language , you can play with memory using C !